# wp-cli search-replace not replace when using regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, wp-cli

I'm using the following command to remove `[download id="XXXX"]` patterns:

```
wp search-replace '\[download id="([0-9]+)"]' ' ' wp_posts --regex --regex-flags='i'
```

But it didn't replace anything.

Comment: Could you show an example of string that should be removed with context?

Comment: @Toto The string is [download id="8212"]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
wp search-replace '\[download id="([0-9]+)"\]' ' ' wp_posts --regex --regex-flags='i'
```

You escaped the square opening bracket, however, left the closing one without a backslash. The regex will fail because you closed a character group that was never opened.

Comment: Same result `Success: Made 0 replacements.`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

```
wp search-replace '\[download id=\"([0-9]+)\"\]' ' ' wp_posts --regex --regex-flags='i'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.